# PyLint doesn't recognize PySide objects

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyside, pylint

I just installed Vscode, created an venv with pew, activated the environment, pip installed Pylint and PySide.

Now Pylint recognize the PySide packages as it's not raising any error or warning at `from PySide.QtGui import *`, but all the PySide objects are getting a `E: 10,23: Undefined variable 'QWidget' (undefined-variable)`. Pylint and PySide are definitely installed in the same environment.

Why Pylint doesn't recognize objects from PySide?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Only I am not using import * and am explicitly importing.

Comment: I spent a while trying to figure this one out, so I'm just going to leave this here in case anyone has the same issue I did. Basically, I had code that looked like: `item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)`, where the `Qt.Unchecked` had a red squiggle, the code would run fine though. Then I finally figured out if I went to the definition of "Qt" (F12), which would open QtCore.pyi, I could search for "Unchecked" and see that it was in an enum named `CheckState`, so if I changed my code to `item.setCheckState(Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)`, it still runs and the red squiggle goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has [happened before](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2817) with PyQt and Pylint. It probably has to do with how Pylint handles `import *` and how `PySide` defines it.

I would try not using `import *` (which is typically frowned upon anyway if you're not in the REPL).